# Accessing messages in Dead letter Queue of ActiveMQ and redeliver to webservice or socket after consumption

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

Iam writing an application in Java using ActiveMQ where iam using a producer and a asynchronous consumer mechanism where the messages sent by the producer are not consumed due to network failures.Hence these messages are sent to dead letter queue of ActiveMQ.

**My question is how to access the messages in dead letter queue and perform retry on the same by consuming it in the consumer and send to a webservice or socket etc.Any code example would be great.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hassen is totally right regarding the possibility to set up a MDB consuming DLQ entries.

However the right place to set up a redelivery policy is on a queue or topic itself (see http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html) and not using the dead letter queue. Indeed you have only one DLQ instance for the MOM which will contain messages from all the different queues / topic and setting up a failover mechanism there will imply to manage the different message structure

Comment: it is possible to use `individualDeadLetterStrategy` too

Comment: but i agree that, if it is possible, it is better to set up a redelivery policy but at the end if messages cannot be delivered they goes to DLQ

Comment: Didn't know that, must be a provider specific feature... Anyway you will lost some message metadata (redelivery count etc...) when falling to DLQ.

Comment: Is it possible to perform redelivery on the messages after they are sent to DLQ

Comment: no they are sent to DLQ after the reach max delivery attempt

Answer (score 4):

DLQ is like any topic or queue and you can subscribe to it like any topic or queue and consume messages accumulated. Here is the list http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

The name of the DLQ to subscribe to it is `ActiveMQ.DLQ` if you not have an `individualDeadLetterStrategy` , you subscribe and do your business onMessage method . 
http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Comment: No my question is not regarding advisory support ,to be more precise i want to retrive the messages in **ActiveMQ.DLQ** and continuously iterate over the messages in the DLQ so that i can perform some redelivery mechanisms

Comment: as i said, DLQ is like any topic or queue and you can subscribe to it like any topic or queue and consume messages